# Calcular y aplicar probabilidad en python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un script, y me he quedado bloqueado en un paso.

Mi duda es la siguiente:

Supongamos que yo tengo la variable `prob = 0.8`, lo que quiero es que `prob` sea la variable que elija entre dos objetos. Ejemplo:

```
prob = 0.8
perro = "Soy un perro"
gato = "Soy un gato"
```

Si prob es 0.8, significa que hay una probabilidad del 80% de que se elija la variable perro, y un 20% de que se elija gato.

Lo siento si no he incuído ningún script de ejemplo, pero no sabía de que manera preguntarlo.

Un saludo,
gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por el lado de **Python** base, no tienes forma de establecer la probabilidad de alguna de las funciones `random` pero nada te impide usar una forma de simular una probabilidad específica, que es trabajar con una lista que respete dicha distribución. En tu ejemplo, podría ser una lista con 80 valores "Soy un perro" y 20 "Soy un gato", luego usar `random.choice()` para obtener uno o más valores de dicha lista. Por ejemplo:

```
import random

perro = "Soy un perro"
gato = "Soy un gato"
prob = 0.8
cant = 100
lista = [perro]*int(prob*cant)+[gato]*int((1-prob)*cant)

resultados = {perro: 0, gato: 0}
for i in range(1000):
  resultados[random.choice(lista)] +=1

prob_perro = (100*resultados[perro])/(resultados[gato] + resultados[perro])
print("Verificamos que probabilidad de {0} es de: {1}%".format(perro, prob_perro))
```

Haciendo esto: `cant = 100; lista = [perro]*int(prob*cant)+[gato]*int((1-prob)*cant)` generamos una lista con 100 valores, 80 para "perro" y 20 para "gato", la cantidad de casos dependerá de las probabilidades en este ejemplo de 80/20 con 100 valores rápidamente llegamos a verificar dicha probabilidad de forma empírica simulando hasta 1000 casos de selección de un elemento al azar.

Por el lado de `numpy` si tienes una forma útil de establecer las probabilidades que es usando [`numpy.random.choice()`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) por ejemplo:

```
# Para generar 100 valores aleatorios con una probabilidad 80/20 
print(numpy.random.choice([perro, gato], size = 100, p=[0.8,0.2]))
```

Con `size` indicamos cuantos valores queremos recuperar aleatoriamente y con `p` indicamos una lista de probabilidad para cada valor inicial.

Comment: Para el script que estoy haciendo, crear 100 variables más no me sería muy rentable... Esta opción la tendré presente, hay alguna otra forma más "reducida" de hacerlo? No me importaría que fuese con algún módulo tipo NumPy. Un saludo y gracias por la aportación :)

Comment: Si, en ese caso podrías usar `numpy.random.choice()`, ahora edito la respuesta.